# SSIS DTS Package flat file error - "The file name specified in the connection was not valid"

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-agent

I have a pretty basic SSIS package that is attempting to read a file hosted on a share, and import its contents to a database table.  The package runs fine when I run it manually within SSIS.  However, when I set up a SQL Agent job and attempt to execute it, I get the following error:

> Executed as user:
>   DOMAIN\UserName. Microsoft
>   (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 9.00.3042.00 for 64-bit 
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp
>   1984-2005. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  10:14:17 AM  Error:
>   2010-05-03 10:14:17.75     Code:
>   0xC001401E     Source:
>   DataImport Connection
>   manager "Data File Local"
>   Description: The file name
>   "\10.1.1.159\llpf\datafile.dat"
>   specified in the connection was not
>   valid.  End Error  Error: 2010-05-03
>   10:14:17.75     Code: 0xC001401D
>   Source: DataAnimalImport
>   Description: Connection "Data File
>   Local" failed validation.  End Error 
>   DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:14:17
>   AM  Finished: 10:14:17 AM  Elapsed: 
>   0.594 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

This leads me to believe it's a permissions issue, but every attempt I've made to fix it has failed.

What I've tried so far:

- Run as the SQL Agent account (DOMAIN\SqlAgent) - yields same error.  DOMAIN\SqlAgent has "Full Control" permissions on both the share and the uploaded file.
- Set up a proxy account with a different account's credentials (DOMAIN\Account) - yields same error.  Like above, "Full Control" permissions were given over the share to that account.
- Gave "Everyone" full control permissions over the share (temporarily!).  Yielded same error.
- Manually copied the file to a local path and tested with the SQL Agent account.  Worked properly.
- Added an ActiveX script task that would first copy the remotely hosted file to a local path, and then have the DTS package reference the local file.  Gave a completely nondescriptive (even by SSIS standards) error when trying to run the script.
- Set up a proxy account, using my own personal account's credentials - worked correctly.  However, this is not an acceptable solution as there are password policies in place on my account, as well as being a bad practice to set things up this way in general.

Any ideas?  I'm still convinced it's a permissions issue.  However, what I've read from various searches more or less says giving the executing account permissions on the share should work.  However, this is not the case here (unless I'm missing something obscure when I'm setting up permissions on the share).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Looks like I had permissions set on the folder, but not on the share. Started working once the permissions were put on the share. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your last test, it's obviously something to do with permissions and a difference between permissions your account has and those that the other accounts do.
What is the protection level of the package?

Comment: It's set as DontSaveSensitive.

Answer (score 0):

i know this post is old, but i just faced the same problem
i think you guys are using "sa" user and it does not have privilege on the folder holding the package, try to log in to SQL with windows authentication , and try to import the package then.

worked for me, hope it will work for you.